# How to extract names of compound present in sub files?

Tags: linux, shell, awk, grep

I have a list of 15000 compound names (file name: uniq-compounds) which contains names of 15000 folder. the folder have sub files i.e. `out.pdbqt` which contains names of compound in 3rd Row. (Name = 1-tert-butyl-5-oxo-N-[2-(3-pyridinyl)ethyl]-3-pyrrolidinecarboxamide). I want to extract all those 15000 names by providing uniq-compound file (it contain folder names e.g `ligand_*`) out of 50,000 folder.

### directory and subfiles

```
sidra---50,000folder (ligand_00001 - ligand50,000)--each contains subfiles (out.pdbqt)--that conatins names.(mention below)
another file (uniq-compound) contains 15000 folder names (that compound names i want).
```

### out.pdbqt

```
MODEL 1
REMARK VINA RESULT:      -6.0      0.000      0.000
REMARK  Name = 1-tert-butyl-5-oxo-N-[2-(3-pyridinyl)ethyl]-3-pyrrolidinecarboxamide
REMARK  8 active torsions:
REMARK  status: ('A' for Active; 'I' for Inactive)
REMARK    1  A    between atoms: N_1  and  C_7
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Assuming, `uniq-compound.txt` contains the folder names and each folder contains an `out.pdbqt`. Also, the compound name appears in the 3rd row of the file `out.pdbqt`. If that is the case below script will work:

```
#!/bin/bash
while IFS= read -r line; do
    awk 'FNR == 3 {print $4}' $line/out.pdbqt 
done < uniq-compound.txt
```

Loop will iterate through the `uniq-compound.txt` one by one, for each line in the file (i.e folder), it uses `awk` to display the 4th column in the 3rd line of the file `out.pdbqt` inside that folder.

Comment: What's the benefit of `cat file | awk 'script'` over `awk 'script' file`? See http://porkmail.org/era/unix/award.html. Also `man xargs` vs using a shell loop.